# How to parse WSDL to generate a form dynamically?

Tags: c#

The standard WSDL form generated by .net is to basic, is there a lib that can help parsing the WSDL so that I can generate a dynamic form myself ?

Also how to intercept the url routing to standard wsdl form so that it would call mine ?